# How should I use a batch script to create other scripts?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm creating a script that I want to be dual-purpose:

1. The script will use user-input options to execute commands to change some settings.  This part is nearly done.

   - The script is collecting the user's choices into local environment variables via `SETLOCAL`/`ENDLOCAL` and `SET /P`, and calling the variables later in the script for command execution.
   - After collecting the user options, there is a verification step that displays those options and asks the user for confirmation before proceeding to command execution.
2. The script will give the user an option to automatically create a new script with their options built-in for future convenience.

Here's my current plan concept to achieve objective #2, though I'm not exactly sure how to write it:

1. Build a template script that can be copied to start off creation of the customized scripts.

   - At the very start of the template script, `SETLOCAL` will isolate environment variables created by the finalized script so they do not persist after the script is finished running.
   - Immediately after `SETLOCAL` will be a `GOTO` command which points to a label at the very end of the script.  The label will be the start of the variable definitions section in completed scripts.
   - After the `GOTO` command will be a label called STARTEXEC that will be jumped to after variable definitions are complete.
   - Just before the variables section label will be a labeled section with some command(s) to exit the script.
2. Into the current script:

   - Add a `CHOICE` during the verification step that asks the user if they'd like to create a static script.  If yes, prompt the user for a filename via `SET /P` then include the script building commands in this script's execution flow via `GOTO`.
3. Use some commands similar to these, to build the static script's variables section:

   `COPY ScriptTemplate.bat %UserFileName%.bat`
   `ECHO SET VAR1=%UserVar1% >> %UserFileName%.bat`
   `ECHO SET VAR2=%UserVar2% >> %UserFileName%.bat`
4. Add one more line to make sure the static script jumps to command execution.

   `ECHO GOTO STARTEXEC >> %UserFileName%.bat`

My questions here:

1. Are my methods fairly sound, or is there a better way to do this, still via batch script?
2. What should I use to exit the static script, before it comes back around to the variables section?  I know I'll need an `ENDLOCAL`.  Will `EXIT` work here, or is there something else more appropriate for this?

Comment: Are you constrained to a Batch-File?

Comment: @Mechaflash Only by my current level of knowledge and experience, but yes.  The scope of this question is limited to batch files only.

Comment: I gave an answer, however, I would suggest looking into AutoIT for projects like this in the future. It's pretty easy to pickup, and you seem proficient enough.

Comment: @Mechaflash Nice answer there, but I'm still a little lost when it comes to loops.

Answer (score 1):

The template idea seems to be the easy method (not sure about short, but this is probably how I would've approached it.) Create a separate template based on the original, removing all of the SET /P commands.

EDIT:

Removed the old answer.

At the end of the template, write:

```
GOTO:EOF

:User_Defined_Variables
```

At the beginning of the file, write:

```
CALL:User_Defined_Variables
```

In your original script, after the user confirms creating a custom script, make a copy of the template file `COPY /y template.bat userscript.bat` send all of the user's variables to it.

```
(ECHO var1 = %uservar1% 
 ECHO var2 = %uservar2%
 Echo var3 = %uservar4%)>> userscript.bat
GOTO:EOF
```

So when the user runs the script, the CALL:User_Defined_Variables will set the user's script parameters and continue on with the rest of the script.

Comment: Nice idea, but I'm confused as to how the loop will work.  (Loops were never my strong suit.)  Particularly, it seems like it's only going to work for a specified number of lines.  What if the number of lines will be variable?  (Some user configurations will require all variables to be defined, some not.)  This is why I was thinking it might be easier to just use `>>` to put the variables at the end, and `GOTO` to jump around the resulting script as needed.

Comment: Give me a snippet of code (just update your original post) where you ask the user for input, and what command runs based on the input, and I can throw together a real example.

Comment: Changed my answer completely.

Answer (score 0):

Iszi,

I have a similar function that we do at my job... we have a different set of custom variables that we use to kick off other functions per customer we deal with. I have written a complex script with Batch that allows myself and coworkers to achieve this, however creating a separate batch file ever time isn't necessary in my opinion.

There are 2 ways I see fit to achieve what you're looking for:

1. You can set all your variables in the beginning and edit them from there
2. You can prompt for your variables every time/write a new script

Either way you do this writing out a batch file to write another batch file is silly and leaves all sorts of potential for error in code. Not only will you be doing error checking on one batch script, but you will have another one.

So here are some examples of what you can do:

1.

```
@ECHO off
TITLE Install Script
COLOR 0A
SETLOCAL

REM ---------------------------
REM  *** EDIT VARIABLES BELOW ***
REM ---------------------------

:sharepath
set sharepath=\\SCIncapps\sharepath
REM SHAREPATH = The location of the files that will be copied to the client machine. List of files you will need in your SCIncIntViewer folder: 
REM vcredist_x86.exe, msxml6.msi,  Browser Access Client Controls.msi,  Automated Update Service.msi, bac.ico, dotnetfx35.exe, dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe,  Episys Client.msi
REM This Sharepath is where the Script needs to be located and has to be an already existing directory

:primaryStaging
set primaryStaging=SCIncweb
REM primaryStaging = The name of the back office server that handles AutoUpdate. This is usually the same as websrvr, except in distributed  environments

:webserver
set websrvr=SCIncweb
REM websrvr = The name of the Web Server; i.e. SCIncweb, SCInc14Doc1, 10.1.1.1, 192.168.1.20, etc.

:install_variables
set dotnet35=F
REM Defines the installation of .NET 3.5 SP 1 as True(T) or False(F)
set dotnet40=F
REM Defines the installation of .NET 4.0 as True(T) or False(F)
set regedit=F
REM Defines the creation of the Registry File to edit all IE settings as True(T) or False(F)
set SSL=F
REM Defines the use of SSL for the BAC URL; SSL is set as True(T) or False(F)
set org=0000
REM Defines the Organization for the BAC url shortcut that is created on the desktop for all users (enter the numeric org #)
set favorite=T
REM This will put the  Browser Access Client URL in their favorite folder and on their browser's quick link bar as True(T) or False(F)
set reboot=F
REM Defines whether or not the script will reboot the machine after it's complete as True(T) or False(F)
REM If using the PsExec.exe to push this script this will force the Domain Administrator to logoff the machine
set reloadAll=F
REM This defines if the _Installed_Files.txt will be overwritten to install all products again as True(T) or False(F)
REM NOTE This will copy down all items and install everything except .NET 3.5 SP1 and .NET 4.0

:creditUnion_Variables
set episys=F
REM Defines the installation of Episys Integration for  as True(T) or False(F)

:bank_Variables
set silver2020=F
REM Defines the installation of SCInc Integration for  as True(T) or False(F)
set coreDirector=F
REM Defines the use of Core Director for banks as True(T) or False(F)
set iseries=1.1.1.1
REM Defines the IP address of the iSeries if in-house Some Company, Inc Core, otherwise irrelevant
set dualinQuiry=F
REM Defines the deletion of the old SCInc Viewer if NOT using Dual Inquiry as True(T) or False(F)
set thinClient=F
REM Defines the /install and /execute flags on a Terminal Server as True(T) or False(F)
set vportsPath=%sharepath%
REM Defines the vports.xml file's location, this variable should be kept as the sharepath unless the client specifies otherwise

:Logs
set PCaudit=T
REM Defines whether or not you want just the PC name to be logged to a file as True(T) or False(F)
REM Creates a list of all the PC's that this script has been run on and puts it in the sharepath folder

REM ---------------------------
REM *** DO NOT EDIT BELOW ***
REM ---------------------------

IF /I '%scanStation%'=='T' goto:eof
REM If running the Scan Station Install tool only the variables are read and then the  Scan Station Install Tool.bat will resume
goto thinClient_inst

:thinClient_inst
IF /I '%thinClient%'=='F' goto date_time
change user /install

:date_time
FOR /F %%A IN ('TIME/T') DO SET time=%%A
REM Sets the time in a proper format for Error Logging
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%B IN ('DATE /t') DO SET date=%%C/%%D/%%E
REM Sets the date in a proper format for Error Logging

:errorLog
REM Logs the error messages for each product that the script attempts to install
IF exist %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt goto PCaudit
echo.Microsoft Website for Errors:> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt
echo.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(VS.85).aspx>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt
echo.(Popular Error: 9009, 1616 :: File does not exist in directory)>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt
echo.--------------------------------------------------------------->> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt
set cleanInstall=0
REM Checks if the ErrorLog file already exists, if not it writes the fist 2 lines which contain the URL for determining the Errors from Microsoft
goto PCaudit

:PCaudit
REM Logs the Computer Name to the Installed_PC text file
REM This checks to make sure that the PC name doesn't already exist in that file and if it does it puts it into another file called %org%_ _Repeat_Installs_Log.txt
verify >nul
IF /I '%PCaudit%'=='f' set PCaudit=F
IF /I '%PCaudit%'=='F' goto start
IF /I '%PCaudit%'=='t' set PCaudit=T
set repeat=F
findstr /x "%computername%" %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_AuditList.txt 
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' set repeat=T
IF /I '%repeat%'=='T' echo.%date% - %time% - %computername%>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Repeat_Installs_Log.txt
IF /I '%repeat%'=='T' goto start
IF /I '%repeat%'=='F' echo.%computername%>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_AuditList.txt
goto start

:start
REM Changes all variables for True(T) and False(F) to capital letters since batch is case sensitive
set HKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
REM This script is meant to be run by a user with ADMIN privledges; 
REM " HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE " registry items can only be edited by an admin

:_done
IF NOT exist "c:\SCInc\ \_done" md c:\SCInc\ \_done
IF NOT exist "c:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt" echo. Installed Files for %computername%: > c:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt
IF /I '%reloadAll%'=='T' echo. Installed Files: > c:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt
goto iviewerUrl
REM Creates the _done folder and the _Installed_Files.txt which will be local to the PC and will keep the products they install to prevent reinstallation
REM Delete this folder to reinstall all products or delete the line of text inside to reinstall a particular product

:iviewerUrl
set iviewerUrl=http://%websrvr%
IF /I '%SSL%'=='T' (set iviewerUrl=https://%websrvr%)
REM This sets the 'iviewerUrl' variable depeneding on if you have SSL enabled or not
set SCIncUrl=/bac/user/User_SO.asp?%OrgName=
REM This sets the rest of the URL for the browser shortcut (the '?' doesn't get a long with batch scripts)

:copy
REM Copies the files from the sharepath to the local machine
echo.
echo.Copying Necessary Files for Installation
echo.This could take a few minutes...
md C:\SCInc\ 
md C:\SCInc\Temp
REM Creates the ' \SCInc\ ' and ' \SCInc\Temp ' directories
goto 1

:1
verify >nul
findstr /x "copy_vcredist" "c:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt" 
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' goto 2
echo.Copying vcredist_x86.exe
copy %sharepath%\vcredist_x86.exe c:\SCInc\temp
REM Copies the C++ Redistributable installer
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.copy_vcredist>> C:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.%date% - %time% - %computername% - There was an error copying vcredist_x86: Error Code %errorlevel%>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt & set cleanInstall=1
goto 2
:2
verify >nul
findstr /x "copy_msxml6" "c:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt" 
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' goto 3
echo.Copying msxml6.msi
copy %sharepath%\msxml6.msi c:\SCInc\temp
REM Copies MSXML 6.0 Parser installer
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.copy_msxml6>> C:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.%date% - %time% - %computername% - There was an error copying msxml6.msi: Error Code %errorlevel%>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt & set cleanInstall=1
goto 3
:3
verify >nul
findstr /x "copy_BAC" "c:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt" 
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' goto 4
echo.Copying  Browser Access Client Controls.msi
copy %sharepath%\" Browser Access Client Controls.msi" C:\SCInc\temp
REM Copies the  Browser Access Client Controls installer
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.copy_BAC>> C:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.%date% - %time% - %computername% - There was an error copying  Browser Access Client Controls.msi: Error Code %errorlevel%>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt & set cleanInstall=1
goto 4
:4
verify >nul
findstr /x "copy_AutoUpdate" "c:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt" 
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' goto 5
echo.Copying  Automated Update Service.msi
copy %sharepath%\" Automated Update Service.msi" C:\SCInc\temp
REM Copies the  Automated Update Service installer
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.copy_AutoUpdate>> C:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.%date% - %time% - %computername% - There was an error copying  Automated Update Service.msi: Error Code %errorlevel%>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt & set cleanInstall=1
goto 5
:5
verify >nul
findstr /x "copy_icon" "c:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt" 
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' goto copy_dotnet35
echo.Copying  BAC Icon
copy %sharepath%\bac.ico %windir%\System32
REM Copies the  Browser icon file to the System32 folder
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.copy_icon>> C:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.%date% - %time% - %computername% - There was an error copying bac.ico: Error Code %errorlevel%>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt & set cleanInstall=1
echo.
echo.Created the following directories:
echo.-------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.C:\SCInc\ 
echo.C:\SCInc\Temp
echo.
echo.-------------------------------------------------------
goto copy_dotnet35

:copy_dotnet35
verify >nul
REM Copies .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5"| findstr Install
REM Checks for .NET 3.5 and installs it if it doesn't find it
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' set dotnet35=F
IF /I '%dotnet35%'=='F' goto copy_dotnet40
echo.Copying and installing .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1
echo.This will take a few minutes...
copy %sharepath%\dotnetfx35.exe C:\SCInc\Temp
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.%date% - %time% - %computername% - There was an error copying .NET 3.5 SP1: Error Code %errorlevel%>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt & set cleanInstall=1

:dotnet35
verify >nul
REM Installs .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1
echo.Installing .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1
echo.This could take a few minutes...
c:\SCInc\temp\dotnetfx35.exe /q /norestart
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.dotnet35>> C:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt & set net35=1
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.%date% - %time% - %computername% - There was an error completing the installation of .NET 3.5 SP1: Error Code %errorlevel%>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt & set cleanInstall=1
echo.
echo.-------------------------------------------------------
echo.
goto copy_dotnet40

:copy_dotnet40
verify >nul
REM Copies .NET 4.0
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"| findstr Install
REM Checks for the FULL (not client) version of .NET 4.0 and installs it if it doesn't find it
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' set dotnet40=F
IF /I '%dotnet40%'=='F' goto msxml60
echo.Copying and installing .NET 4.0
echo.This could take a few minutes...
copy %sharepath%\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe c:\SCInc\temp
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.%date% - %time% - %computername% - There was an error copying .NET 4: Error Code %errorlevel%>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt & set cleanInstall=1

:dotnet40
verify >nul
REM Installs .NET 4.0
echo.Installing .NET 4.0
echo.This could take a few minutes...
c:\SCInc\temp\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe /q /norestart
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.dotnet40>> C:\SCInc\ \_done\ _Installed_Files.txt & set net40=1
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.%date% - %time% - %computername% - There was an error completing the installation of .NET 4: Error Code %errorlevel%>> %sharepath%\%org%_ _Installed_PCs_ErrorLog.txt & set cleanInstall=1
goto msxml60
```

Above script is partial and was edited.

As you can see I set all my variables in the beginning of my file. This way every time I need to change something I'm never going to the code to do so, same with my coworkers. Some of them are capable of changing it some are not, those that are not have an easy time understanding what to change because everythign is set in the first 70 lines of the file.
The reason I think this is the best way to go is because I have the flexibility to change things on the fly. I have variables that trigger other installations that I might want to stage later. With a script that creates another script you may find yourself lacking the ability to change things w/o rerunning your first batch file.

```
@echo off
> usermessage.vbs ECHO WScript.Echo InputBox( "What is the name of the Service you want to restart?", "Service:", "MspSvc" )
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('CSCRIPT.EXE //NoLogo usermessage.vbs') DO SET Service=%%A
ECHO You will restart %Service%
DEL usermessage.vbs

net stop %Service%
net start %Service%

Pause
```

This is from Rob Vanderwoude. He has probably the single most used website for Batch script commands I know of. I've altered this piece to take the input of the user and use that to write my variable for restarting services. This could work for what you want to do for writing a script that writes another script..

If this is the case then what you're going to want to do is this:

```
@ECHO off
TITLE Script Creator
COLOR 0A
SETLOCAL

> usermessage.vbs echo.WScript.Echo InputBox( "Pick something to test SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL on?", "Variable:", "OUTSIDEVARIABLE" )
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('CSCRIPT.EXE //NoLogo usermessage.vbs') DO SET outsideVar=%%A
echo.Your variable is %outsideVar%
DEL usermessage.vbs

echo.%outsideVar% is still set outside

echo.@echo off>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.COLOR 1B>>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.SETLOCAL>>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.cls>>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.set insideVar=%%outsideVar%% >>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.^> usermessage.vbs echo.WScript.Echo InputBox( "Pick something to test SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL on?", "Variable:", "INSIDEVARIABLE" ) >>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.FOR /F "tokens=*" %%%%A IN ('CSCRIPT.EXE //NoLogo usermessage.vbs') DO SET insideVar=%%%%A >>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.DEL usermessage.vbs >>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.echo.Your variable is %%insideVar%% >>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.echo.You have set the Second Variable: %%insideVar%% in this new batch file! >>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.echo.%%insideVar%% is now Inside the new batch >>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.Pause >>c:\temp\newbatch.bat
echo.ENDLOCAL >>c:\temp\newbatch.bat

echo.You are about to run the new batch file
pause
call c:\temp\newbatch.bat

cls
pause
echo.You created a batch file that set your outsideVar variable in it
echo.%outsideVar% is still set outside

ENDLOCAL
REM Install Batch Script
REM Created by Trevor G.
```

In this script we have a unique way of making sure that each line will be written to the end of the new batch script, but also you need to remember key things here... there are times when you will need to use the ^ (carat) and times when you will need to double up your %% to make sure that both your variables will be passed through and also that you're not triggering another command within your script before writing that to the new one.

Comment: Your script is *way* too long.  Please reduce the example to a relevant sub section to show your answer.  You don't need the *whole* script.  Additionally, do not post *another* answer as a continuance, this is considered *noise* and it will be deleted as such.  If you can't fit it into one answer, then it's a good indication that you've said *too much*.

Comment: And we definitely *want* you to be helpful, but we also want everyone to aspire to a level of quality that helps *everyone*; that said, it's not the answer is *bad*, but it can be made *better* and we always want the users of SO to *make things better*.  Look at your answer, see what is *truly required* (instead of a code dump with lots of irrelevant bits) and whittle it down to that; you'll find that it will be *much* better received (in the form of upvotes).

Comment: Also, note that the "Hope this helps" and the signature part of your message should be edited out, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: You should see it differently. SO has defined some standards when posting questions and answers, and we expect everyone to comply with them. If you are not for some reason, we will try to point what is wrong, and what should be done, so that you don't repeat the same mistakes in the future. SO is no different than any other community, be it on the Internet, or in real life. Communities have rules, and they expect everyone to follow them. Don't get so discouraged, most of your posts are quite good, but need only a slight adjustment.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments and respect what you are doing, I have made the changes (within minutes of seeing my error that you pointed out) and would now appreciate the focus to be on the work that I did provide for the user asking a question. I hope the next response here will be focused on the actual problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why the error checking of both scripts is really that big of a deal.  Once the generating script and template script are completed, the only error checking that needs to be done is on the variables in the scripts auto-generated later.  These will be only a handful, and placed at the very end of the final script.  Also, is this all in straight Batch?  The syntax doesn't look familiar.

Comment: The later part of my post uses wscript in batch, but it could easily be set /p variable=: and wait for user input.

I find error checking to be good practice, but which part are you referring to?